# Is it possible to pull and close connection in PyMongo?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am curious: if it is still possible to **`iterate`** over a **`cursor`** when the connection is **`closed`**.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
    db=client.sample
    collection=db['sample']
    cursor = collection.find({})
    client.close() # Closing
    for document in cursor:
        print(document)
```

For optimization, to reduce connection redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by simply converting the `cursor` into `tuple` like this

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
    db=client.Sample
    collection=db['sample']
    documents = tuple(collection.find({}))
    client.close() # Closing
    for document in documents:
        print(document)
```

converting a  cursor into tuple will do an actual query into db. But it has its own issues related to it, not an efficient way either.

Comment: Hi, I just tried in my machine. And it works, but I didn't do the `tuple` conversion.

Comment: So what's more efficient then?

Comment: it depends on the use case. And why do you really want to close a connection? A connection to the mongo db should be made when your application starts and should be closed when application terminates. A pymongo client will not open a connection until the first request to db.